# What is the name of the database or table?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new to Google App Engine and `NDB` and am studying https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore.

The example in there works, but where is the name of the database or entity group specified?  How does the application know to use the same database every time?  How do I not accidentally query or write to someone else's database if he is also running the same application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every application on App Engine uses the same datastore, but each application can access only its own entities. So there is no need for a database name.

All instances of your app have access to all entities inside the datastore that your app created. You, as the app developer, can implement various access restrictions based on a user id or a user role. For example, you can enforce that each authenticated user can only read his own messages and unauthenticated users have no access to messages at all, or that a user with a system admin role can delete other users and their messages.

You can use [Multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/) if your app serves a number of distinct customers and you want to keep their data separate. This, however, is mostly done for convenience and to prevent accidental mistakes in your code - you can achieve the same effect by simply using a customer id in your data models and in queries.

Comment: What identifies my database?  If say I have built up a database of guestbook sign in's from this demo app, how can I create another totally separate web application to query this database?

Comment: you can give access to one applications datastore to another application.

Comment: A second application can act as an authenticated user in the first application. The choice of a way to communicate between apps depends on your use case. A popular approach is to use a RESTful API for these apps to talk to each other, which makes one app less dependent on changes in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

A Datastore Kind is analogous to a table in a relational database.  With NDB, each Model corresponds to a Kind and by default the Kind's name is the name of the Model subclass that you define.  In the example you refer to it would be "Greeting".

The entity group is specified using the parent parameter to the Model's constructor.  In the example you refer to, you can see a parent being passed to the Greeting constructor.

Within App Engine, each Application essentially has its own Datastore so you don't need to specify that - the environment figures it out for you.

Comment: While true, I prefer not to think of a kind as a table, because the datastore is NOT relational, and thinking in "relational equivalencies" just seems to make the transition to an HRD environment weirder.

Comment: @Peter McKenzie: I printed out guestbook_key(guestbook_name) and was expecting some GUID, but I got a string: `Key('Guestbook', 'default_guestbook')`

Comment: Patrice: fair enough. I think the analogy is useful if not taken too far.  Old Geezer: Try calling the id() method on that Key.

Comment: Oh definitely. I was just pointing to the "risk" of trying to map everything to an RDBMS. But you're right. The closest to a "table" the datastore has is entities :)